# Flutter Fetch API

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Im trying to fetch data from external api, but my screen show this error message:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
```

My Screen code is this:

```
class PricesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PricesScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<PricesScreen> createState() => _PricesScreenState();
}

class _PricesScreenState extends State<PricesScreen> {

  late Response response;
  Dio dio = Dio();
  var apidata;

  bool error = false; //for error status
  bool loading = false; //for data featching status
  String errmsg = "";

  getData() async {
    String baseUrl = "https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/last/USD-BRL";

    Response response = await dio.get(baseUrl);
    apidata = response.data;
    print(response);

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      if(apidata["error"]){
        error = true;
        errmsg  = apidata["msg"];
      }
    }else{
      error = true;
      errmsg = "Error while fetching data.";
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData(); //fetching data
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: loading?
        const CircularProgressIndicator() :
        Container(
            child:error?Text("Error: $errmsg"):
            Column(
              children:apidata["data"].map<Widget>((coin){
                return CurrencyContainer(
                    name: coin["name"],
                    increase: coin["varBid"],
                    symbol: coin["code"],
                    value: coin["high"]
                  );
              }).toList(),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

My print message show the data from api:

```
{"USDBRL":{"code":"USD","codein":"BRL","name":"Dólar Americano/Real Brasileiro","high":"5.1856","low":"5.1856","varBid":"0.0004","pctChange":"0.01","bid":"5.1851","ask":"5.186","timestamp":"1669850610","create_date":"2022-11-30 20:23:30"}}
```

I tried to access data as 'apidata = response["USDBRL"]' but it show error: lib/screens/prices.dart:27:23: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Response'.

- 'Response' is from 'package:dio/src/response.dart' ('../../snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-4.0.6/lib/src/response.dart').
  Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  apidata = response["USDBRL"];

How can i show the data in screen?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is accessing the data, to do that, simply access using:

```
response.data['USDBRL']
```

You got the error because you are trying to access the `USDBRL` from the response object itself. The data returned from the api should be inside the `data` attribute of the response object.

Answer (score 0):

`if(apidata['error'])` this is causing the error becsuse `apidata['error']` is null and can't be used as bool

```
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
        error = false;
        errmsg  = '';
      }
```

and you can access data with

```
 apidata['USDBRL']
```

Comment: I access it now, but my screen show error on map:
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.

Comment: I tried like this: apidata.map<Widget>((coin) and apidata['data'].map<Widget>((coin)
But it dont worked. Any idea?
My apidata is this now: {code: USD, codein: BRL, name: Dólar Americano/Real Brasileiro, high: 5.1856, low: 5.1856, varBid: 0.0004, pctChange: 0.01, bid: 5.1851, ask: 5.186, timestamp: 1669854405, create_date: 2022-11-30 21:26:45}

Comment: `Response response = await dio.get(baseUrl)`
 ` apidata = response.data as Map<String dynamic>;`
`apidata['USDBRL'].map<Widget>....`

Comment: i tried it, but dont work.
I tried on the previous way and got: The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map<Widget>(Closure: (dynamic) => CurrencyContainer)
The file is: https://github.com/FischerRobson/traveler-wallet/blob/main/lib/screens/prices.dart